# Возможно ли без дублирования кода реализовать сортировку по различным полям в таблице?

Tags: сортировка, symfony, querybuilder

доброго дня, нужно реализовать на бекенде сортировку записей из таблицы по различным полям которые берутся с помощью Doctrine QueryBuilder и выдать на rest api endpoint, можно ли как-то параметризовать запрос в базу так чтобы не дублируя в десятке методов запрос на выборку получить записи отсортированные по одному из полей?

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Comment: Тогда отметьте ответ

Comment: не мог найти где отметить вопрос как решенный...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В builder'e есть метод `orderBy`:

```
$builder->orderBy('field');
```